# Python argparse: metavar and action=store_true together

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse module in Python to parse parameters typed in a command line interface. I have the following add_argument call to a subparser object:

```
submit_parser.add_argument('-pv','--provision',metavar='PROVISION', dest='PROVISION',
                                 help='provision system',
                                 action='store_true', default=False, required=False)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scripts/tp4", line 94, in <module> 
    main()
  File "./scripts/tp4", line 74, in main 
    modloader.loadModules(sub_parsers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tp4/cli/Moduleloader.py", line 66, in loadModules 
    registered_modules[module_name].setSubparserArgs(module_sub_parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tp4/cli/modules/AutotestModule.py", line 135, in setSubparserArgs
    action='store_true', default=False, required=False)
  File "/usr/share/tp4/cli/zip/argparse.zip/argparse.py", line 1302, in add_argument
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metavar'
```

If I remove action or metavar parameters, it works. Why both can't be together? There is nothing about this restriction in argparse documentation at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: python version.... is an important thing to be checked....

Comment: Not that you asked, but if `action` is `'store_true'`, the default value is already `False` (and if action is `'store_false'` the default value is `True`).  It's quite convenient, though different from `optparse` (where the default is `None` in both cases).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A metavar only makes sense for positional arguments (think filenames at the end of the command line) or for when an argument takes arguments of its own (like `--input-files foo.txt bar.txt`).

Your `--provision` argument is a flag because you set the `action` to `store_true`. It doesn't take any arguments (i.e., `nargs` isn't set). As such, it doesn't make sense to have a metavar.

From [the `argparse` documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#metavar):

> When `ArgumentParser` generates help messages, it need some way to refer to each expected argument. By default, `ArgumentParser` objects use the dest value as the “name” of each object. By default, for positional argument actions, the dest value is used directly, and for optional argument actions, the dest value is uppercased. So, a single positional argument with `dest='bar'` will be referred to as bar. A single optional argument `--foo` that should be followed by a single command-line argument will be referred to as FOO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, this information is not explicit in argparse documentation.

Comment: For sparse python docs, I invariably end up getting my answers from the PYMOTW website, http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/

Comment: I was using `metavar=` when what I really wanted was `dest=`.

Comment: I have landed here twice now and will reiterate comment by @aldo

Use 
dest"

Answer (score 1):

To extract an answer from @pwc, you need to use `dest` instead of `metavar`.